# Can set value to hidden field on change set value to hidden field?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
                <title> </title>
                <style type="text/css">
                </style>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function setPrice(selObj){
                        document.forms['f1'].price.value = selObj.options[selObj.options.selectedIndex].value;
                }
                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form name='f1'>
                        <select name="category" onchange='javascript: setPrice(this);'>
                                <option value=''>Select an option</option>
                                <option value="41">Men</option>
                                <option value="39">Women</option>
                                <option value="20">Under 18's</option>
                        </select>
                <input name="price" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
        </body>
</html
```

Are there any problems with the code,because I did not see the update value in  hidden field ?

Comment: What is the question? Your script is working fine.

Comment: Are you asking what i think you're asking? Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: yes,I tried but it not working FF 3.6.8

Comment: are sure it works fine??

Comment: I tried in FF 3.6.8 (linux)...works great
http://jsfiddle.net/FwTgb/

Comment: What are you using to check the value? If you just right-click and view source even with FF I don't thinkyou will see dynamic changes to the DOM. Use FireBug or something similar.

Comment: yes.,you are right.thanks for your inform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering: YES!

You can change the value of a hidden with onchange.
You already did this in your code.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/FwTgb/